# Do textures that are inside a shader resource need to be explicitly released too? (DirectX 11)

Tags: c++, directx11

I have a ID3D11Texture2D (that I've created manually) inside a ID3D11ShaderResourceView. When I want to `Release()` the resource view, do I need to `Release()` the texture that it is inside too? Or is it not necessary to do so?

Msdn doc and Google couldn't help me on this one. :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  Any reference you have to a D3D object needs a `Release()` call when you're done with it.  It doesn't matter whether another object might also have a reference to it.  The object will not be deleted until all references to it are gone, so it's safe to `Release()` the texture as soon as you don't need the pointer to it anymore.  If it's also referenced by an SRV, that reference will keep it alive until the SRV is also deleted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So this would be okay to do?
HRESULT res = d3dDevice->CreateShaderResourceView(ret_texture, &desc, &SRV);
ret_texture->Release();
// ... Do more stuff with SRV object

Comment: @Kaboose Yes, that should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I would add to the prior answer a discussion about bound Shader Resource Views and a distinction between D3D10 and D3D11. Microsoft changed the behavior when binding resources such that the D3D11 runtime holds a reference to the resource until you bind something else to whatever slot it is on.

D3D10 *did not* do this and various swapchain operations that require you to release all resources will fail if you do not clear all SRV bindings first in D3D11 (but not D3D10). You may have implicit references floating around even if you have released every resource you ever created.